# postgresql password authentication failure

Tags: postgresql, heroku, windows-7

I have installed PostreSQL, I have the Heroku toolbox, and I'm still trying to just get started.

From my Windows command prompt, I type `psql` and it asks for a password, and I type in the one I provided when installing PSQL, and it still gives me:

```
C:\Users\Tina\Desktop\FriendActivity>psql
Password:
psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "Tina"
```

I have even tried:

```
C:\Users\Tina\Desktop\FriendActivity>psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres:
psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

This is a fresh install. First time trying to use it.

I was trying to follow these steps here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup

but

```
export DATABASE_URL=postgres:///$(whoami)
```

does not work:

```
    C:\Users\Tina\Desktop\FriendActivity>export DATABASE_URL=postgres:///$(whoami)    
'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have been trying to get this set up to use for a class project that uses a database for a few days now... and I cant seem to get this to work.

the project we are working on is here:

https://github.com/rwprice31/FriendActivity

My part is getting the database functionality working.

Answer (score 0):

You are following instructions written for Linux or Mac OS X. They will not work on Windows.

The Windows equivalent of:

```
export DATABASE_URL=postgres:///$(whoami)
```

is

```
set DATABASE_URL=postgres://localhost/databasename
```

where you should replace `databasename` with the name of the database you wish to connect to.

---

As for:

```
> psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres:
psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

I can only assume that you made a mistake entering the password when you set it up, or you had an old PostgreSQL data directory already in place from a past install.

Either way, you'll need to reset the password. There are many instructions here for doing that, so I won't repeat them.

---

Regarding:

```
>psql
Password:
psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "Tina"
```

Presumably there is no user named Tina in PostgreSQL. The installer would usually only create a `postgres` user when installed.

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling those weren't windows commands.. but they did not give windows instructions.  And,  If you could maybe direct me to  some of those instructions for resetting the password  I would be quite happy.

Comment: @CDavis10 First Google hit for "reset postgresql password windows" is http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19643/how-do-i-reset-the-postgres-password-for-postgresql-on-windows . There are many similar questions too. General idea: twiddle pg_hba.conf, reload service, connect, `ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'blah'`, undo `pg_hba.conf` changes, reload service again